# Does a USB 3.0 connection require a USB 3.0 cord?

Tags: usb, cable, usb-3

Does a USB 3.0 connection require a USB 3.0 cord to reach USB 3.0 speeds (SuperSpeed)? Will any USB cord support any USB 3.0 device?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The *SuperSpeed* transfer mode requires a USB 3.0 or higher cable.  Earlier spec cables will still make a connection but at a slower rate.

---

**Source 1:** [USB 3.0 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0)

> The VBUS, D−, D+, and GND pins are required for USB 2.0 communication.
>   The additional USB 3.0 pins are two differential pairs and one ground
>   (GND_DRAIN). **The two additional differential pairs are for
>   SuperSpeed data transfer**; they are used for full duplex SuperSpeed
>   signaling.

---

**Source 2:** [USB 3.0 Super Speeds - USRobotics](http://www.usr.com/en/education/usb-30-peripherals/)

> USB 2.0 cables can be used with 3.0 ports but the transfer rate will
>   fall back to 2.0

---

**Source 3:** [Are USB 3.0 cables different? - Answers - UserBenchmark](http://www.userbenchmark.com/Faq/Are-USB-30-cables-different/21)

> Yes, to get USB 3.0 speeds, you need special USB 3.0 cables. Yes, USB
>   3.0 cables are different. Even though you can connect a USB 3.0 device via a USB 2.0 cable, in order to achieve full USB 3.0 speeds you need
>   to re-wire any existing cabling. USB 3.0 cables are generally thicker
>   because they have nine internal wires versus four on USB 2.0 cables.

Comment: Is there any substance in the "usually blue" claim?

Comment: @MartinArgerami The usually blue applies to the plug (not the cable) - "Since USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 ports may coexist on the same machine and they look similar, USB 3.0 specification mandates appropriate color-coding and recommends that the Standard-A USB 3.0 connector has a blue insert (Pantone 300C color). The same color-coding applies to the USB 3.0 Standard-A plug"

Comment: There's a semi-official colour scheme I've noticed with sockets - USB 3's blue, USB 2.0 charging connectors (which are powered even when the PC they are off) are sometimes yellow. I'd rather look at the connectors for identification since I have blue usb 2.0/1.1 cables.

Comment: I understand that it's a quote, but I think that “will fall back...” should really be “will not magically increase”.

Comment: For completeness, it's worth mentioning that 10GB USB3.1 ports (twice as fast as the 3.0 standard) are commonly a lighter shade of blue.  I don't know if this is an official recommendation or not; but has held with most of the 3.1 board prototypes I've seen so far.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz "magically increase" is probably a bit unfair; it's not an unreasonable assumption that the same cable could carry more data due to a better protocol/communication standard. Such a phenomenon has occurred multiple times for the simple copper wire used in telecoms.

Answer (score 61):

#### A "USB 3.0 connection" requires a USB 3.0 cable.

Some **USB 3.0 devices** can be connected and operated as a USB 2.0 device (at USB 2.0 speeds), using a USB 2.0 cable.  However, speed is not the only issue.

There are at least **three important differences** in cable construction between the two standards.

#### Related to speed:

- **The USB 3.0 cable has 9 internal conductors vs. 4 in USB 2.0.**

  Four of the nine match the USB 2.0 configuration (two are for power and two are for signal).  Connecting a USB 3.0 device with a USB 2.0 cable uses those conductors and operates like a USB 2.0 device.

  The other five are signal conductors, which are used for the communication method that provides USB 3.0 "superspeed" (a good general description can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0)).
- **USB 3.0 cables have a limit of 3 meters vs. the USB 2.0 limit of 5 meters.**

  *(Note that this is a practical limit.  The cable can be any length as long as it meets all of the electrical requirements in the specification.  The 3 meter limit is based on maximum allowable losses using the largest recommended wire size so that the cable is flexible.)*  source: [specs](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/usb_31_060115.zip)

#### Related to power:

- **A USB 2.0 cable may not be adequate for a high current USB 3.0 device.**

  Some USB 3.0 devices draw more power than USB 2.0 devices.  The power conductors in USB 3.0 cables need to be able to carry 900mA instead of 500mA for USB 2.0.

---

Additional information on USB 3.0 vs. 2.0 can be found [here](http://www.diffen.com/difference/USB_2.0_vs_USB_3.0).

Comment: yep, it works with legacy USB speeds using legacy cords.

Comment: What about UTP? http://superuser.com/questions/937437/making-usb-extension-cables-using-utp-cable?noredirect=1#comment1273499_937437

Comment: @arielnmz: To achieve USB 3 speeds, the specs define the performance characteristics the wire needs to meet.  I'm not familiar with whether UTP could meet the requirements, but the spec is here: http://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/technical-specification/usb3-internal-connector-cable-specification.pdf

Comment: And note the reverse on power:  I have a USB2 device that draws too much power, it originally had a two-headed cable that let it draw power from two ports at once.  Now it's fed from a single USB3 port with no gripes about drawing too much.

Comment: +1 extra pins/cores are required in USB3 to reach the higher rate.

Comment: Just a quick question,  what about if I have a usb 2.0 harddrive with Y-cable,  can I replace with USB 3.0 cable for a better current?

Comment: @Bilo: If you plug it into a USB 3 port it should work (a USB 2 port limits the current output to 500mA). But that's a waste of a USB 3 port. You would be better off getting a USB 3 enclosure for the drive and taking advantage of 10x the speed.

Comment: @fixer1234 unless it's an SSD you wont get anywhere near 10x the speed, even a really good spinning disk is going to top out somewhere around the 100MB/s mark. If it's a cheap or old drive it might well not even saturate USB2.

Comment: @JosephRogers, you're right.  The USB port will be a bottleneck as long as it's slower than the peak transfer rate.  You don't need to saturate it; performance will be degraded if the peaks exceed the bandwidth.  On a good hard drive, that can be several times the USB 2.0 limit.  With a good drive, you can benefit from USB 3.0's 10X speed, but you won't realize 10x the transfer rate.  That was poor wording in my comment.

Answer (score 14):

USB 3.0 jacks will work with older USB 2.0 cords, but at USB 2.0 speeds. The newer [USB 3.0 connectors have more wires](http://www.moddiy.com/pages/USB-2.0-%7B47%7D-3.0-Connectors-%26-Pinouts.html) to carry the higher data rate.

Comment: Is it the same with USB 1 cables? Will USB 1 cords work in a USB 3 jack at USB 1 speeds; or will they not work at all?

Comment: @user568458 - USB 2.0 is backwards compatible with USB 1.0 and USB 1.X cables and devices.  Since USB 3.0 devices plugged into a USB 2.0 port will act like a USB 2.0 device this means a USB 3.0 device when plugged into a USB 1.0 or 1.x port will act like a USB 1.0 or 1.x device.

Comment: @user568458 All USB cables were identical before USB 3.0.